# In react JS how can i set footer component at the bottome of all pages, either the page have some content or not?

Tags: reactjs, footer

When I use footer component in react ,  footer does not  set at the bottom of the page if that page is empty or do not have enough section. So how can I fix it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

place it below the  like so:

```
import "./index.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import About from "./pages/About";
import Products from "./pages/Products";

function App() {
  return (
        <>
          <Router>
            <NavBar />
            <div>
              <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
                <Route path="/products" element={<Products />} />
              </Routes>
              <Footer />
            </div>
          </Router>
        </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

By doing so, it will ensure that all the pages, with or without content have the set footer appearing at the bottom of each page. Hope it help you solve your problem